# How to add a tooltip for this calendar made in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this calendar(nicedaypicker) and with help of backend php,i get some events dates in an array (var events =[]; the format of a value is: ex: 2019/11/10 ) ,and i want to add a tooltip just for dates that are in that array.

```
    this.$warpper.addEventListener('load', function (e) {

 i want to make something here to add a tooltip class on load of calendar
        }, false);
```

```
    var events = [];



(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
        typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
            (global.calendar = factory());
}(this, function () {
    'use strict';

    var calendar = function ($params) {
        this.$warpper = null;
        this.monthData = null;
        this.$params = $params;
        this.init(this.$params);
    };

    calendar.prototype.getMonthData = function (year, month) {
        var year, month;
        var ret = [];

        if (!year || !month) {

            var today = new Date();

            year = today.getFullYear();

            month = today.getMonth() + 1;
        }
        var firstDay = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);

        var firstDayWeekDay = firstDay.getDay();

        if (firstDayWeekDay === 0) {

            firstDayWeekDay = 7;
        }

        year = firstDay.getFullYear();

        month = firstDay.getMonth() + 1;


        var lastDayOfLastMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 0);

        var lastDateOfLastMonth = lastDayOfLastMonth.getDate();

        var preMonthDayCount = firstDayWeekDay - 1;

        var lastDay = new Date(year, month, 0);

        var lastDate = lastDay.getDate()
        var styleCls = '';
        for (var i = 0; i  lastDate) {
                thisMonth = month + 1;
                showDate = showDate - lastDate;
                styleCls = 'nice-gray';
            } else {
                var today = new Date();
                if (showDate === today.getDate() && thisMonth === today.getMonth() + 1) {
                    styleCls = 'nice-normal nice-current';
                } else {
                    styleCls = 'nice-normal';
                }


            }

            if (thisMonth === 13) {
                thisMonth = 1;
            }
            if (thisMonth === 0) {
                thisMonth = 12;
            }

            ret.push({
                month: thisMonth,
                date: date,
                showDate: showDate,
                styleCls: styleCls
            });
        }
        return {
            year: year,
            month: month,
            date: ret
        };
    };

    calendar.prototype.buildUi = function (year, month) {
        this.monthData = this.getMonthData(year, month);
        this.dayWords = [['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Gio', 'Ven', 'Sab', 'Dom'], ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su']];
        this.enMonthsWords = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];


        var html = '' +
            '' +
            '<';

        if (!this.$params.mode) {
            this.$params.mode = 'it';
            html += '' + this.monthData.year + '年 - ' + this.monthData.month + '月';
        } else if (this.$params.mode === 'en') {
            html += '' + this.enMonthsWords[this.monthData.month - 1] + ',' + this.monthData.year + '';
        } else if (this.$params.mode === 'it') {
            html += '' + this.monthData.year + '年 - ' + this.monthData.month + '月';
        }

        html += '>' +
            '' +
            '' +
            '' +
            '' +
            '';
        if (!this.$params.mode) {
            this.$params.mode = 'it';
            for (var i = 0; i ' + this.dayWords[0][i] + '';
            }
        } else if (this.$params.mode === 'en') {
            for (var i = 0; i ' + this.dayWords[1][i] + '';
            }
        } else if (this.$params.mode === 'it') {
            for (var i = 0; i ' + this.dayWords[0][i] + '';
            }
        }
        html += '' +
            '' +
            '';

      for (var i = 0; i ';
            }
            html += '' + this.monthData.date[i].showDate + '';
            if (i % 7 === 6) {
                html += '';
            }
        }


        html += '' +
            '' +
            '' +
            '';


        return html;

    };

    calendar.prototype.render = function (direction, $params) {
        var year, month;
        if (this.monthData) {

            year = this.monthData.year;
            month = this.monthData.month;

        } else {
            year = $params.year;
            month = $params.month;
        }
        if (direction === 'prev') {
            month--;
            if (month === 0) {
                month = 12;
                year--;
            }
        }
        if (direction === 'next') {
            month++;

        }
        var html = this.buildUi(year, month);
        this.$warpper.innerHTML = html;
    };
    calendar.prototype.init = function ($params) {
        this.$warpper = $params.dom;
        this.render('', $params);
        var _this = this;
        this.$warpper.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            var $target = e.target;
            if ($target.classList.contains('prev-date-btn')) {

                _this.render('prev');

            }
            if ($target.classList.contains('next-date-btn')) {

                _this.render('next');

            }
            if ($target.classList.contains('nice-normal')) {

                $params.onClickDate($target.getAttribute('data-date'));

            }
        }, false);
        this.$warpper.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
            var $target = e.target;
            if ($target.classList.contains('nice-normal')) {

                $target.classList.add('nice-active');


            }
        }, false);
        this.$warpper.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
            var $target = e.target;
            if ($target.classList.contains('nice-normal')) {

                $target.classList.remove('nice-active');


            }

        }, false);
            this.$warpper.addEventListener('load', function (e) {


        }, false);

    };
    return calendar;
}));
```

Comment: We are seeing too much of your script.  Narrow your question and show only what needs our attention.  If you want to present array data as a single string, then the function to research is `join()`.

Comment: No, i just want to make a loop through the created days of a month,and if a date is find in the array to add a tooltip to it.But i do not know how to loop through the created days